# how to programmatically add/remove displays in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if there is a way to programmatically add and remove Displays in rviz? I would think that if the feature existed it would come in the form of a topic or service that a node can publish to or call to add or remove a Display of a certain DisplayType.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9722/how-to-programmatically-add/remove-displays-in-rviz/) by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 674 on 2011-04-13

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz does not have an API to do that currently.  I suggest that you file a [feature request ticket](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/new).

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on 2011-06-02**:
just did it -> https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/396